# Debugger not breaking at breakpoint inside livedata observer? (Gif attached) Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-livedata

[image]

Using Android Studio 4.0. This is in a viewpager so not all swipes will trigger the breakpoint as it creates left and right fragment. But as you can see the issue is that it never wants to stop at the breakpoint inside the live data observer, as you can see I clearly have a timber log that gets added to logcat, and obviously the code is working. What's going on? Never had this problem before.

Things I have tried:

- set minifyEnabled to false in debugging build in gradle (just a suggestion i came across)
- right click on breakpoint, set to "all" instead of "thread"

Source code for the project: https://github.com/giancarlogatti/Notify/tree/reworking-dao-setup

If anyone tests this by any chance there's also other LiveData examples inside CreateEditAlarmFragment that I have had problems as well